# React Native with expo, fail to connect metamask wallet ( TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined, js engine: hermes)

Tags: react-native, expo, blockchain, solidity, metamask

I am trying to connect my app with the meta mask wallet through the SDK but it fails with the following error:

`[ TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHash' of undefined, js engine: hermes\]`.

Really Appriciate anybody could help.

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7c92qrMBT4&t=530s)

**Here is my code**

metro.config.js:

```
const { getDefaultConfig } = require("@expo/metro-config");

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
defaultConfig.resolver.sourceExts.push("cjs");

defaultConfig.resolver.extraNodeModules = {
  ...require("node-libs-expo"),
};

defaultConfig.transformer.getTransformOptions = async () => ({
  transform: {
      experimentalImportSupport: false,
      inlineRequires: true,
  },
});


module.exports = defaultConfig;

// module.exports = {
//   ...defaultConfig,
//   resolver: {
//     ...defaultConfig.resolver,
//     extraNodeModules: {
//       ...defaultConfig.resolver,
//       ...require("node-libs-react-native"),
//     },
//   },
// };
```

metamask.ts:

```
import MetaMaskSDK from "@metamask/sdk";
import { Linking } from "react-native";
import BackgroundTimer from "react-native-background-timer";

export const MMSDK = new MetaMaskSDK({
  openDeeplink: (link) => {
    Linking.openURL(link);
  },
  timer: BackgroundTimer,
  dappMetadata: {
    name: "BALLOTEXPRESS",
    url: "https://mydapp.com",
  },
});
```

menu.js:

```
import "node-libs-expo/globals";
import "node-libs-react-native/globals";
import "react-native-url-polyfill/auto";
import  { MMSDK }  from "../metamask.ts";
import "react-native-get-random-values";

export default function ElectionMenu() {
    const handleCastBallot = async () => {
        await MMSDK.connect();
        const ethereum = MMSDK.getProvider();
        const accounts = await ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
        console.log(accounts);
      };

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Election Menu</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleBack} style={styles.backIcon}>
          <Icon.Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={35} color="black" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      <CustomButton
        text="Cast Your Ballot"
        imageSource={goVote}
        onPress={handleCastBallot}
      />

      <CustomButton
        text="View Election Result"
        imageSource={result}
        onPress={handleViewResults}
      />

      <CustomButton
        text="View Vote Transaction"
        imageSource={transaction}
        onPress={handleViewTransactions}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

depencency(package.json)

```
{
  "name": "fyp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^13.0.0",
    "@metamask/sdk": "^0.16.0",
    "@metamask/sdk-react": "^0.16.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.16",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.9",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native-background-timer": "^2.0.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.3",
    "babel-plugin-inline-import": "^3.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "eciesjs": "^0.3.18",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.4.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~2.4.13",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "^2.3.1",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^14.7.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-local-authentication": "~13.4.1",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.14",
    "expo-screen-orientation": "~6.0.6",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.8.0",
    "node-libs-expo": "^0.0.3",
    "node-libs-react-native": "^1.2.1",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.10",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "~1.9.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-orientation-locker": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-redash": "^18.1.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^13.9.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.0.3",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.2.2",
    "readable-stream": "^1.0.33",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "react-native": {
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify"
  },
  "browser": {
    "_stream_transform": "readable-stream/transform",
    "_stream_readable": "readable-stream/readable",
    "_stream_writable": "readable-stream/writable",
    "_stream_duplex": "readable-stream/duplex",
    "_stream_passthrough": "readable-stream/passthrough",
    "stream": "stream-browserify"
  }
}
```

I follow [this documentation](https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/how-to/use-sdk/javascript/react-native/) but also does not work. I want to connect to meta mask and use it for my blockchain voting app(ethereum solidity)